# AAppend an element to the root

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to append a tag to the roo of my xml file, however I'm getting an error on createElement :

```
if(hashValidationRulesAtt.get("mandatory").equals("true") && (elemValue==null||elemValue.equals(""))){
                        DOCUMENTS.appendChild(doc.createElement(statusKO));}
                    else{
                        DOCUMENTS.appendChild(doc.createElement(statusOK));
                    }. Any help

if(hashValidationRulesAtt.get("mandatory").equals("true") && (elemValue==null||elemValue.equals(""))){
                        DOCUMENTS.appendChild(doc.createElement(statusKO));}
                    else{
                        DOCUMENTS.appendChild(doc.createElement(statusOK));
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append the root element to the document and then append the childelements of the root to the root element.
Here is a bit of an example

```
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Expenses");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);

        for (String s : list)
        {
            Element element = doc.createElement(type);
            element.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(s));
            rootElement.appendChild(element);
        }
```